# How to rearrange rows of a dataframe according to the values of a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am working on a dataframe that has a column named **season**. Each season has many matches. The order of season is to be rearranged.
Season order is `2017,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2018,2019`.

I want to bring all the rows of the season 2017 after 2016 season rows.

The data looks like this, (renamed **id** to **match_id**, few columns are shown here, in total there are 18)

```
    match_id    season  city        winner
0   1           2017    Hyderabad   Sunrisers Hyderabad
1   2           2017    Pune        Rising Pune Supergiant
2   3           2017    Rajkot      Kolkata Knight Riders   
3   4           2017    Indore      Kings XI Punjab
4   5           2017    Bangalore   Royal Challengers Bangalore
```

I tried this,

```
df.set_index('season')
```

and then,

```
df.reindex([2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019])
```

but the output was horrible,

```
        match_id    season  city    winner
2008    NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN 
2009    NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN
2010    NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN
2011    NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN
2012    NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN
2013    NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN
2014    NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN
2015    NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN
2016    NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN
2017    NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN
2018    NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN
2019    NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is sorting by ordered categoricals with order by `list`:

```
L =[2008,2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015,2016,2017, 2018, 2019]
df['season'] = pd.Categorical(df['season'], ordered=True, categories=L)

df = df.sort_values(['season','match_id'], ignore_index=True)
```

Or you can create dictionary with enumerate for mapping in `key` parameter:

```
L =[2008,2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015,2016,2017, 2018, 2019]

d = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(L)}
df = df.sort_values('season', key = lambda x: x.map(d), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: yes from both of these queries the sequence of the season is arranged (2017 in between 2016 and 2018),   but the matches/id sequence is falsy now.

Comment: the original id column values were like this, season: 2017 id range: 1-59, season: 2008 id range: 60-11                                                                          
After these queries, Each season's id sequence is like this now. i.e.                                                             Now 2017's id sequence is 1,59,28,27,26,.....,42,43,44,40.                                                                                   
2019's id sequence is 11332,11335,11334,11333,....,11317,11318,11319,11321.                   Note: id is not index, it is a column.

Comment: according to the id column the sequence of rows should be, (from 2008 to 2019). 2008's 60-117, 2009's 118-174, ........., 2016's 577-638, 2017's 1-59, 2018's 7894-7953, 2019's 11137-11415.

Comment: sure i will read these.

Comment: see the question again.

Comment: match_id sequence is still not correct, i.e. 2008's match_id new sequence: 117,83,82,80,..., 73,84,72,...,60,71,85,....,88,115,114,113.

Comment: this is the result of dictionary query. The first solution ( catagories---list) gave error.  ValueError: Categorical categories must be unique

Comment: @FaheeemSajjad - need sorting? So first solution change to `df = df.sort_values(['season', 'match_id'], ignore_index=True)` ?